# Customizing the android studio navigation drawer by changing the drawer border

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

[image]

I am trying to figure out a way to customize the navigation drawer in android studio as shown below. I want to be able to have a curved design in the top right corner where I can close the navigation drawer and also open the navigation drawer by clicking on it as shown in the video.